# Facing issue while importing robot

Tags: pycharm, robotframework, automation-testing

I am new trying to learn AutomationTesting and I am facing this error  "Error in "import robot".
It seems that Robot Framework is not installed in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3.
Please install it in your environment and restart the Robot Framework Language Server
or set: "robot.language-server.python" or "robot.python.executable"
to point to a python installation that has Robot Framework installed.
Hint: with pip it can be installed with:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install robotframework. "
Can someone please help me?

I try everything but I don't know what is the  problem here

Comment: What does "try everything" mean? Did you try what it suggests: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install robotframework`?